# Remove string sign from array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I am having an array

```
myArray= ["{ depth: 1, display: 'X' }", "{ depth: 2, display: 'X.X' }", "{ depth: 3, display: 'X.X.X' }", "{ depth: 4, display: 'X.X.X.X' }", "{ depth: 5, display: 'X.X.X.X.X' }", "{ depth: 6, display: 'X.X.X.X.X.X' }"]
```

I need my output array like this

```
expectedResult = [{ depth: 1, display: 'X' }, { depth: 2, display: 'X.X' }, { depth: 3, display: 'X.X.X' }, { depth: 4, display: 'X.X.X.X' }, { depth: 5, display: 'X.X.X.X.X' }, { depth: 6, display: 'X.X.X.X.X.X' }]
```

I tried with this

```
myArray.map(item => {
               const container = {};
               container[item.depth] = item.display;
               console.log(JSON.stringify(container));
               return container;
             })
```

But it gives undefined. How can I solve this?

Comment: You want `JSON.parse()`, not `JSON.stringify`. That being said, it's not going to work because the strings in the array are not valid JSON. You need to amend them so that they are valid JSON, ***however*** if you can edit the response then it'd make more sense to just not use JSON at all.

Comment: Working backwards to get the 'JSON' you would need: `var x = { depth:1, display:"x" };JSON.stringify(x)` gives `'{"depth":1,"display":"x"}'`

Comment: If it's only and always "depth" and "display", you could use reg ex to extract the values and create a new object.

Comment: You don't need ``JSON.parse()`` or RegEx, you can do it with ``arr.map(item => (new Function('return ' + item))() )``, which is flexible to any object, which is in a string format that JavaScript can parse.

Comment: That was not my intention, but I could see how you could read it like that. My apologies. I should have phrased it "an alternative to X & Y is Z". Did not mean to offend you. I just wanted to point out that Javascript has a powerful way to parse strings. There are always several ways to achieve the outcome. One doesn't make another invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this by creating a function with a string constructor (this is not the same as using eval):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

```js
const myArray= ["{ depth: 1, display: 'X' }", "{ depth: 2, display: 'X.X' }", "{ depth: 3, display: 'X.X.X' }", "{ depth: 4, display: 'X.X.X.X' }", "{ depth: 5, display: 'X.X.X.X.X' }", "{ depth: 6, display: 'X.X.X.X.X.X' }"];

const myOutput = myArray.map(item => {
  /* 
   * according to mozilla using Function("return something")
   * is better then eval() - and doesn't use eval
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!
  */ 
  return (new Function('return ' + item))();

})

console.log(myOutput)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```